# In C, if the array is initialised while declaration then the dimension is optional. Why?

Tags: c

In C, if the array is initialised while declaration then the dimension is optional. Why?

Comment: Because the compiler can figure it out.  It's a convenience.

Comment: So it is compiler dependent ? In some cases ,we might find that this doesn't work ? @davidbak

Comment: You cannot use declaration-only with an initialiser. It is always a definition.

Comment: It's part of the language definition, you can depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you tell it to create an array holding a `1`, `2`, and `3`, it can easily figure out the required size since you gave it 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare array like `int a[10];`
You are specifying compiler about memory of 10 elements

and if you declare like `int a[] = {1,2,3};`
You are specifying compiler that you want memory of only 3 elements